# pkg_resources: get own distribution?

Tags: python, package

I want to find the distribution of a file. The file should discovery its own distribution.

I tried this, but this does not work:

```
import os
import pkg_resources
for dist in pkg_resources.find_distributions(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    print dist
```

The file with the of the above was installed using `pip install -e ...`.

I could not find a solution in the docs:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#distribution-objects

The solution should not contain the string of the package. It should be generic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pkg_resources` distribution APIs need a *distribution name*; this does not necessarily correlate with the *package name* the 'current' module is operating under.

Take the BeautifulSoup project, for example. The current version uses `bs4` as the package name, but the *distribution name* on PyPI is [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4).

A distribution can contain more than one top-level package or module, too; the `pkg_resources` module itself is part of the `setuptools` distribution for example, together with the `setuptools` package.

As such, you *cannot* generalize and use `__file__` or `__package__` and hope to always get the corresponding distribution.

If your distribution was installed as an egg (using `easy_install` or `zc.buildout` for example), then you can search for the `.egg` extensions in the path, split the path at that location and use [`Distribution.from_filename()`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#getting-or-creating-distributions) to produce a `Distribution` object from that; the filename contains all the information necessary. If your package was installed using `pip` however, a separate `.egg-info` file is created instead and you are back to square one (no distribution name locatable).

In the other direction, you can get all `Distribution` objects for your environment with a [`pkg_resources.Environment()` instance](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#environment-objects); but you'll run into the same problems matching existing distributions to a given module or package, at least not with the public API. You *could* scan all distributions, the combination of the `.location` attribute (for eggs) and perhaps the (private) `Distribution._provider` attribute together with (entirely optional) presence of a `installed-files.txt` metadata entry (which if is available, contains relative paths(!)) would let you scan your whole environment for a matching distribution, but this is entirely dependent on the internal implementation details of the various [resource providers](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#built-in-resource-providers). And it could potentially be an expensive search, certainly for larger installations.

As such, your best option is to just use a hardcoded distribution name.

Comment: Well, going "the other direction", for each distribution you may get at `.get_metadata('top_level.txt')` which gives you all top level packages, at least for pip installed ones.